# Drawing a smooth outline around points in a polar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using matplotlib I have generated the polar plot below, which shows the angle and distance to aircraft nearby (calculated using the haversine formula).  This plot is composed of 56132 individual points.

[image]

The code for this is almost the same as the examples from the documentation:

```
ax = plot.subplot(111, polar=True)

# Orient the plot with north (0 degrees) to the top
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0, top=100)

c = plot.scatter(r, t)
plot.savefig('test.png')
```

Where `r` is a list of radian angles and `t` is the corresponding distance.

I can also process the data and just draw the outline.  To do this I converted all radian angles to 0-359 degrees, found the highest distance measurement and plotted the result with a line:

[image]

My specific question is: can I somehow draw a smoother outline around the points?  Preferably filled with a gradient outward from the centre.

However if anybody can suggest general ways of making this data more visually appealing that would also be excellent.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to fill the area, you might consider a pseudocolor heatmap (pcolor), or a filled contour (contourf), which are available in matplotlib (For example: http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolor). Getting them to work in this case might be tricky - you might need to convert your plot points to a rectangular grid in order for it to work.

Alternatively, you could try finding the several percentile values for each angle, (instead of just the largest) and draw multiple lines in different colors.